# Implementing "likes" in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database-design, sqlalchemy

Implementing "likes" in many applications is really trivial task. However, the problem with likes in application I'm currently developing is: there are many entities that can be "liked" (e.g.: post, photo, etc.).

I've currently rolled out a simple `Likeable` class, which manages likes. My likes table looks like that:

```
like_table = Table('like', metadata,
                   Column('id', Integer, Sequence('like_id_seq'),
                          primary_key=True),
                   Column('entity_id', Integer, index=True),
                   Column('entity_type', String(32)),
                   Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id')))
```

When creating a new like, `entity_type` is assigned by this `Likeable` to reflect type of liked element.

However, I know that this is far from good practice. **How should I implement likes and what my database schema should look like to make it more SQLAlchemish?**

Comment: does this help http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GKNG0FdfTqMJ:www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy%40googlegroups.com/msg22962.html+sqlalchemy+dynamic+table+references&cd=18&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=cl&source=www.google.cl

Comment: Don't you have `entity_type` column on the `entity` table already?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Generic Associations](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/examples.html#generic-associations) example from SA. It does exactly what you are after.
The code is in the `example` directory of the installation or can be browsed [here](http://hg.sqlalchemy.org/sqlalchemy/file/74c4ef8e0d24/examples/generic_associations).
The simpliest implementation [discriminator_on_association.py](http://hg.sqlalchemy.org/sqlalchemy/file/74c4ef8e0d24/examples/generic_associations/discriminator_on_association.py) is what resembles your code most.